# Android nested fragment navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

How in the right way implement nested navigation with Android Navigation component?
For example if we have 2 fragment outer and inner with 2 navigation graph. How i can navigate (get navigation controller) outer fragment from inner in the right way?

[Code example from github](https://github.com/MakcNmyc/NestedNavigationSample?organization=MakcNmyc&organization=MakcNmyc)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I mean having separate nav graph and separate nav controller for the nested navigation?

Comment: Yes and have the same problem like example - how determine outer controller from inner fragment. I used bad workaround with static method to activity like "Navigation.findNavController(fragment.requireActivity(), R.id.content_main_navigation_container)".

Comment: @Makc did that workaround work?
I have the same issue, and I'm passing the right navController but can't navigate.
Providing more context, I have a outerFragment and then a innerFragment1 and innerFragment2 with a different navController.
Inside of the innerFragment2 I can find the outerFragment's navController with that Navigation.findNavController and giving the activity and id.. but when trying to navigate using that navController it doesn't work, so I only can navigate from the inner naController

Comment: @danfbfern it works for me. Make shure you put ID FragmentContainerView of outerFragment

Comment: @Makc damn, its weird because I provide the right id for the FragmentContainerView and even log it to see if its the same instance of the navController in the outer fragment.
It finds the right navController, but does nothing, doesn't navigate (but if I provide the inner navController it navigates)..
Other than the view id, do you have any other possible ideia as to why it does nothing if I provide the right outer navController?